# Потеря данных при изменении ориентации Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Здравствуйте! я начинающий прогер и не могу разобраться помогите пожалуйста.
Есть NavigationView и несколько фрагмент страничек. 
Проблема: например я нахожусь в фрагменте категории и переворачиваю устройство и сбрасываются данные и переходит на главный экран.
Как решить эту проблему?

---

Код OnCreate() главного активити  :

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);
       //убрал ненужные коды
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        transaction.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment_main).commit();
}
```

и вот метод onNavigationItemSelected():

```
 switch (item.getItemId())
     {
         case R.id.nav_main :
      transaction.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,fragment_main).commit();
             break;
         case R.id.nav_report_category:
             transaction.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,fragment_category).commit();
             break;

         case R.id.nav_history:
             transaction.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,fragment_history).commit();
             break;
     }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Мой магический шар говорит, вы в onCreate добавляете в активити фрагмент и не проверяете при этом есть ли уже в активити другой фрагмент.

Т.е. вам надо проерять есть ли фрагмент и только если его нет - добавлять главный фрагмент.

Также, если фрагмент у вас, не дай боже, в разметке указан - уберите его оттуда и добавляйте программно.

Comment: я тоже так делаю с методом  transaction.replace().

Comment: но проблема не в этом. а при изменении ориентации экрана

Comment: Думаю это связано с OnCreate()  Navigation Drawer 'a . но не знаю как решить

Comment: при повороте экрана не сохраняется текущий фрагмент

Comment: Вы где-то отображает первый фрагмент. Где- можно лишь гадать-кода не видно